# Sharing On Instragram From Reactnative And Pasting Link from clipboard

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, types

Sharing on instagram and pasting copied link from the app at the same time is not working. Technically the instagram share relies on the UIpasteboard which the clipboard library also relies on so the linked copied is overwritten when the button to share on instagram is clicked on

Tried Using React native share and expo clipboard but cant seem to get it working

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the code you're using and any errors you get to your post. See [ask] and how to make a [mcve] when you can.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.